# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.User.Name is blank on MySite creation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

We have a sharepoint feature which gets activated on 'MySite' creation. We need to get the logged in user's active directory user name in that feature...So we have used 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.User.Name 
but it throws following exception
"System.ArgumentException: Account name cannot be an empty string."

Any idea why is it blank ? Or is there some other way where we can get logged in user's AD user name ??

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName`

Comment: This won't work in my case for example if the logged in user belongs to Administrative group then instead of showing actual AD user name it always shows DOMINANAME\System Acount

Comment: That should only be the case if the logged in user is the System Account.  What administrative group are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about "Mysite". 
However in general you need to have "Integrated windows Authentication" selected.  You may reach to this option via

> IIS->website->properties->Directory
>   Security->Authentication and Access
>   control -> Edit

Also if have your web.config you should have authentication mode as "windows".

If it is not helpful post more info about the "feature", 
how it is coded? 
where is is published?